# Correct physical refraction

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Blender 2.92 Cycles, I'm trying to model a quartz prism with physically correct refraction of a beam of light cast by a narrow slit (not worried about the color dispersion yet). But when I render it, the beam of light doesn't bend, and it doesn't seem to exit the prism in any meaningful way at all. According to my calculations, it should go horizontal inside of the prism, and exit at a symmetric angle to how it entered.

I'm using a plain ol' glass material for the prism with an index of refraction of 1.6, although I get the same results using the principled shader. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

[image: Basic setup]
[image]

Edit: Also, if I change the prism to 100% glossy metal, it doesn't cast a sharp reflection caustic of the beam either. I'd expect to see a discrete blue reflected beam on the floor here, instead of the soft glowy caustic I actually got. Maybe Cycles can't actually do these kinds of things... or is there a "use actual optics" setting I can turn on?

[image]

Comment: Cycles doesn't really support caustics that well if I'm correct, most people just find ways to fake it. Have you tried Luxcore?

Comment: I might be wrong, but although it's called PBR "physically based rendering" it doesn't have the capabilities of a real scientific simulation to recreate real world examples - or at least not in a considerable amount of time since you always limit samples, bounces etc. to keep render times in acceptable ranges. But as the name indicates, it is "physically _based_", not "physically _correct_".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann (As a non-biased 'brute force' engine, Cycles *is* physically accurate with *infinite amount of samples*) :)

Comment: Also related: [How to simulate glass dispersion with only one Principled BSDF node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/201085/78972)

Comment: As I said, I might be wrong. but since you never let Cycles render forever you'll never get an accurate result. I mean with usual settings it's hard to even get any light through this prism...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann No, you're right about any practical situation, I was just being pedantic (didn't have my coffee yet) :)

Comment: @brockmann OP says specifically he's not concerned about color dispersion.

Comment: @brockmann Not really though?  In real life dispersion is a combination of the fact that light bends *and* that different colors bend differently.  But when trying to create that look in Cycles, the two (colorful refractions and angle of refracted light) don't necessarily have the same solution at all.  Note none of the answers to either of the linked questions talk about the angle of the reflected light, only getting fancy colors.

Comment: @NascentSpace I actually just discovered Luxcore! Will have to have a look.

Comment: @JachymMichal it doesn't seem to be physically accurate in this case... if I let it run for infinite time, it looks like the engine would still be converging toward a solution where the light beam passes straight through the glass without bending at all. I may look into Luxcore for a more accurate simulation.

Comment: I wonder how you've set up scene, because when I try something I cannot see the light beam inside, only when it comes out, and then it's very faint and with lots of fireflies. However, it's not going straight through, it comes out at an angle that changes with the IOR. The problem is that Blender doesn't split up the white light into different colors, it comes out as white. Even if Cycles may be physically accurate it's not taking white light as a spectrum of different wavelengths, it just gets bend as one white beam according to one IOR.