# How to light a glass object in order to give a neon effect?

Tags: lighting

I have a glass object (uneven surface) that I want to light in order to give it a neon effect. Something sort of like this

[image]

The above image was done in cinema 4d but I'm sure there is way to achieve this in Blender. Is this purely a light setup? If yes, how?

Comment: Looks like a 'crystal' glass dispersion shader.  This is fairly easy to do in Blender since the addition of the White Noise Texture. @vklidu has a good answer here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201937/110840